# generic c# class for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations in asp.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, data-access-layer

I'm searching for a code example/link that does what the title says.

Basically I need to create a data access layer for my asp.net website, and I want it to be as generic as possible. I prefer to work with stored procedures and data tables and the respective c# ado.net code for the sake of performance.

If anyone has comments/suggestions/corrections please feel free to say it.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx) is for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing the [`DataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks, sounds pretty straight foreward, do you know of a code example of how to use it for stored procedures ?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use/learn `LINQ-SQL`, `Entity Data Model` framework, and EDM `code first`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the sample from this one in the past. It was really well done. I added what I needed but as a generic DAL it was pretty solid.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Generic_DAL_in_NET_20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dapper is what StackOverflow uses: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Here is a list of other ORMs: 
http://amrelgarhy.com/47/orm-tools-net/

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlHelper Class from Microsoft Enterprse Library.Data Application Block.